# How to control multiple python scripts with respect to time and make the system failure proof

Tags: python, architecture, safety-critical

I need to run multiple Python scripts daily, which prepare and deliver critical data and stop the scripts after a predefined time. Then, run a different script (only one time) to achieve the generated outputs. The important part is that this should be repeated daily, and if a script causes failure, including the control script, then restart the failed script again.

What is the state of art way of doing this control? How can the system made to be failure proof? I can of course do it with sleeps and exception handling and to run subprocesses I could use popen. Can we say that this approach is good enough?

Comment: have a look at [`sched`uler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html)

Comment: You can use [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/)